# java Iterator minigame

Tags: java, iterator

```
    public static void updatePlayers() {

    Iterator iterator = waitingRoom.keySet().iterator();
    System.out.println("Test 1");
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Player player = (Player) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Test 2");
 if (player != null) {
        System.out.println("Test 3");
 player.getPA().sendString("@yel@Start:" + ((gameStartTimer * 3) + (timeRemaining * 3)) + "", 199);
 player.getPA().walkableInterface(197);
    }
}
```

so i have been working on this minigame and i'm not sure what's happending to my iterator it is not working for some reason.

the problem is this

```
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Player player = (Player) iterator.next();
```

Bacially it doesn't load test 2 hence this is not working for some reason.

it's suppost to check load the lobby on my minigame the timer.

```
public static void startGame() {
    if (getSaraPlayers() < 1 || getZammyPlayers() < 1) {
        gameStartTimer = GAME_START_TIMER;
        return;
    }
    gameStartTimer = -1;
    System.out.println("Starting minigame.");
    gameStarted = true;
    timeRemaining = GAME_TIMER / 2;
    Iterator iterator = waitingRoom.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Player player = (Player) iterator.next();
        int team = waitingRoom.get(player);
        if (player == null) {
            continue;
        }
        player.getPA().walkableInterface(-1);
        player.getPA().movePlayer(GAME_ROOM[team - 1][0] + Misc.random(3), GAME_ROOM[team - 1][1] - Misc.random(3), 1);
        player.getPA().movePlayer(GAME_ROOM[team - 1][0] + Misc.random(3), GAME_ROOM[team - 1][1] - Misc.random(3), 1);
        gameRoom.put(player, team);
    }
    waitingRoom.clear();
}
```

Comment: Your problem description is very vague. Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: Seems like ```waitingRoom``` is empty.

Comment: So i have been working on this minigame right? And i was learning how to use iterator for it to work and for some reason it doesn't reach test 2

Comment: @balent it is not empty i've checked that already when user joins player lobby it adds them into it both lobbys but the interface iterator doesn't work aka the timer and interface doesn't show up.

Comment: @guythatneedshelp at what point is `waitingRoom` not empty?

Comment: [09-05-17 04:14]: Test 1
[09-05-17 04:14]: Test - UpdatePlayers();
But test 2 doesn't load waitingroom is not empty because i've tested it and it added the player 1 and 2 to each lobbies

Comment: I'm willing to post the whole .java class if needed

Comment: Yes, please do post the whole code

Comment: https://hastebin.com/wuteguvilo.java hope this makes it easier :p

Comment: @guythatneedshelp try printing out the value of `waitingRoom.size()` at the top of `updatePlayers()`.  If it shows anything other than zero and you're still not getting to the point where "Test2" is printed, I'd be frankly surprised, but it would definitely be something to talk about...

Comment: @KevinAnderson https://hastebin.com/pexalakomi.md it does shows 0 whenever i join the waiting room with any of my chars to adds +1 every time and also -1 everytime someone leaves as it should.

Comment: @guythatneedshelp doesn't matter what it shows when characters are joining and leaving.  What does it show at the top of `updatePlayers()`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson i showed you https://hastebin.com/pexalakomi.md it shows 0 :)

Comment: Well, size of zero means it's empty.

Comment: @KevinAnderson oh i thought it was all put together? So what does this mean?

Comment: `waitingRoom` starts off empty, size==0.  Add character "A", now size==1; add character "B", size==2; remove "A", size==1; remove "B", size==0.  Not quite sure what you mean by "all put together".

Comment: @KevinAnderson So if you check the hastebin i sent you with everything in it you would understand what i mean but is there any fix for this?

Comment: @KevinAndersons https://hastebin.com/gagusubayo.vbs

Comment: The problem is not with the Iterator itself.  You're using it perfectly correctly, and it is working exactly like it should.  The problem is that there is, at that point, for some reason, there's nothing in `waitingRoom` to iterate over.

Comment: @KevinAnderson that makes no sense :C So i've done it right but it doesn't work?

Comment: @KevinAnderson so what do i do to fix this problem?

Comment: No, you've done it right and it works perfectly, just not the way you'd like.  It works the way it does because `waitingRoom` is empty at that point.  That happened _before_ you called  `updatePlayers()`.  So start by follow the trail back to whatever calls `updatePlayers()` and see where that leads.  Concentrate on code that does anything to `waitingList`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson i've already sent you this once but i'll resend it to you if you haven't seen so https://hastebin.com/wuteguvilo.java this is the whole java class i'm coding it in and this is where all waitinglists are. About updateplayer() i am calling updateplayer() in my server.java file where everything is loaded up upon running the base.

Comment: @KevinAnderson ps this is the problem not waitinglists as far as i see, https://hastebin.com/xorucezoze.cs

Comment: Well then you need to extend to reach of your vision.  Here's what I see: the only place in the `CastleWars` class that adds things into `waitingRoom` is the method `toWaitingRoom`, which in turn gets called from `addToWaitRoom`; nothing in `CastleWars` calls `addToWaitRoom`.  So how does anything ever get added to `waitingRoom`.  Can you show me any code that calls the `addToWaitRoom` in `CastleWars`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson this https://hastebin.com/gogofirava.swift calls it bacially you enter the portal and it calls that.

Comment: Ok, the code you're showing certainly _could_ call `addToWaitRoom`.  Does it actually get executed?  Also, at the bottom of `startGame()` there is the call `waitingRoom.clear()`.  That empties `waitingRoom`.  Does `startGame()` somehow get called before `updatePlayers()`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson startGame() doesn't get called at all https://hastebin.com/amihahanew.cs since it can't even load the lobby waittime/interface and yes the addToWaitRoom works fine

Comment: It's clear to me that `CastleWars` is not the class in charge here.  Something else is pulling all the strings.  The only way you're going to figure this out is to set breakpoints on all the relevant methods and physically see what's being called and in what order.

Comment: @KevinAnderson i'm gonna be honest i'm pretty sure it has something to do with castlewars what else would it be?

Comment: OK, if you think that's where the problem is, then that's where you start _debugging_ instead of wasting your time chatting with me.  Get in there and debug the crap out of it until you figure out what's going on.  Set breakpoints on every bloody method and watch how they're called and where they were called from, single-step through them, examine every stinking variable you can.  We are programmers; this is what we do.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I like the way you go about things, Thanks norless i'll reply back when i figure something important out :)

Comment: @KevinAnderson Found out the problem and it has nothing to do with the castlewars.java it had something to do with the castlewars.process was put the wrong place, I feel so stupid after spending this much time trying to figure out why the heck it didn't work oh well it's fixed now and thanks alot for trying to help me out Kevin :)

Comment: Glad I could help.